# PDF manipulation - images are distorted after few consecutive operations on PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, encryption, ms-word, mpdf

I've run into this weird issue with PDF file handling. Not sure if SO is the right place to ask this, but I couldn't find any specific sites for this. I hope that someone can shed some light on the issue.

This happens with the following specific process, if some of steps are omitted - the issue is not observed.

I have a PHP application that serves PDF files to users. These files are created by authors in MS Word 2007, then printed to protected PDF (using pdf995, most likely, I can confirm if needed).
I'll call this initial PDF file as 'source' hereinafter.

Upon request, the source file is processed in PHP the following way:

we decrypt it using [qpdf](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf):

```
qpdf --decrypt "source.pdf" "tmp_output.pdf"
```

Then we add security label / wartermark to it, encrypt and output to browser using [mPDF 6.0](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html):

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->SetImportUse();

$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile($fpath);
if ($pagecount) {
    for ($i=1;$i<=$pagecount;$i++){
    $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($i);
    $mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);

    $html = '[security label / watermark contents...]';

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
   }
}

$mpdf->SetProtection(array('copy','print'), '', 'password',128);

$mpdf->Output('final_output.pdf','I');
```

With the exact steps described above, images in the output that were pasted in the Word doc appear as follows:

[image]

In the source PDF, tmp_output (qpdf decrypted file) the pasted images look correct:

[image]

The distortion doesn't take place if any of the following occurs:

- Word doc printed to PDF without protection
- mPDF output is not protected.

As you can see there too many factors, so I don't know where to look for a bug.
Each component works correctly on it's own and I cannot find any info on the issue. Any insights are greatly appreciated.

## EDIT 1

After some more testing, it appears that this only happens to screenshots taken from web browser, Windows explorer, MS Word. Cannot reproduce this with screenshots from Gimp.

It appears that something along the way attempts to convert white to alpha and fails.

Comment: Can you please share all PDFs which are used/produced in the described workflow?

Comment: @JanSlabon I don't have access to any file sharing services here, and it is not possible to attach files to questions. What to do?

Comment: @JanSlabon OK, here it is [download](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07245342052483679163) password:pdf

Comment: It looks like mPDF has a problem with octal notation in PDF strings. They will not get interpreted but in a string value of "\000" the string \000 will be encrypted as a whole instead of a single byte with the value 0x00. Feel free to report this issue [here](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf). They are simply missing to unescape the string as e.g. done [here](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI/blob/master/fpdi_bridge.php#L85).

Comment: I just made a [pull request](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/pull/441) to Mpdf which should solve this issue.

Comment: @JanSlabon Wow, some deep knowledge there. Thanks a ton! Is my understanding correct - string encoding varies among different PDF producers and mPDF fails to handle all cases properly? hence the issue is only observed in particular scenario.

Comment: @JanSlabon kindly convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version (6.1) of Mpdf has a bug which does not handle escaped PDF strings (imported via FPDI) correct if they should be encrypted.

A pull request, which fixes this issue is available [here](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/pull/441).